# Are there first person accounts of monothematic delusions?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, reference-request, psychiatry, schizophrenia, psychosis

[Monothematic delusions](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/delusion/#TypDel) are delusions that concern a single topic ([Davies et al. 2001](https://muse.jhu.edu/login?auth=0&type=summary&url=/journals/philosophy_psychiatry_and_psychology/v008/8.2davies.html)). They are often the result of acquired brain damage and include the [Delusional Misidentification Syndromes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusional_misidentification_syndrome), such as [Capgras delusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capgras_delusion) (which involves the conviction that a close relative or spouse has been replaced by an impostor), as well as [Cotard delusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotard_delusion) (which may involve the conviction that one is dead) and [somatoparaphrenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatoparaphrenia) (which involves the conviction that a limb or an entire side of one's body is not one's own).

While there are untold numbers of [first person (experiential) accounts](http://schizophrenia.about.com/od/livingwithschizophrenia/a/schiz_experien.htm) of schizophrenia and, therefore, schizophrenic delusions (which usually present as polythematic), from [Daniel Paul Schreber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Paul_Schreber)'s *Memoirs of My Nervous Illness* (1903) to [Elyn Saks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elyn_Saks)'s *The Center Cannot Hold* (2007) and [various accounts published in *Schizophrenia Bulletin*](http://schizophreniabulletin.oxfordjournals.org/search?tocsectionid=First%20Person%20Account&sortspec=date&submit=Submit), I have not come across first person accounts of any monothematic delusions so far.

Answer (score 2):

Since asking the question, I was able to locate a first-person account of monothematic delusion, namely, of denial of ownership of one's own limbs ([somatoparaphrenia/asomatognosia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatoparaphrenia)). It is due to the neurologist and writer [Oliver Sacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Sacks), who in his fourth book *A Leg to Stand On* (1984) described his recovery after a fall in a remote region of Norway in which he injured his leg. Following surgery to reattach his quadriceps muscle, he experienced an emotional period in which his leg no longer felt a part of his body. He describes his confusion, seeing the “disowned” plastered limb (Sacks 1984: 45,49, 49–50):

> I had felt the leg in front of me . . . but now I could see it wasn’t
>   there at all but had got shifted and rotated. . . . I had a
>   sudden sense of mismatch, of profound incongruity –
>   between what I imagined I felt and what I actually saw,
>   between what I had “thought” and what I now found. I felt, for
>   a dizzying, vertiginous moment, that I have been profoundly
>   deceived. . . .

The experience of touching the leg was “inconceivably shocking and uncanny”:

> I seemed to have lost “my leg” – which was absurd, for there it
>   was, inside the case, safe and sound – a “fact.” How could
>   there be any doubt in the matter? And yet there was. On this very matter of “having” or “possessing” a leg, I was
>   profoundly doubtful, fundamentally unsure.

This alarming state of uncertainty later resolves itself into
what seems closer to a fully delusional state:

> [the leg] became a foreign, inconceivable thing, which I looked
>   at, and touched, without any sense whatever of recognition or
>   relation. It was only then that I gazed at it, and felt I don’t
>   know you, you’re not part of me, and, further, I don’t know this
>   “thing,” it’s not part of anything. I had lost my leg. Again and
>   again I came back to these five words: words which expressed
>   a central truth for me, however preposterous they might
>   sound to anyone else. In some sense, then, I had lost my leg.
>   It had vanished; it had gone; it had been cut off at the top. I
>   was now an amputee.

**EDIT**: I have found a first-person account of Cotard delusion in [this blog post](http://the-toast.net/2014/06/25/perdition-days-experiencing-psychosis/view-all/), thanks to [Vaughan Bell](http://www.national.slam.nhs.uk/about-us/our-experts/dr-vaughan-bell/) who found it through [Keith Frankish](http://www.open.ac.uk/Arts/philosophy/frankish.shtml) (both authors working extensively with delusions).